# How to cancel holding of a package

Tags: apt, package-management

I got a MID based on ubuntu os.The version if its software is pretty old.So I decide to upgrade the system.But apt-get upgrade does not work,it appears packages are prevented from upgrade.I can I unlock them

Thanks

Comment: A bit more information could be useful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some packages (like the kernel) can only be upgraded with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

For pinned packages, have a look at the `/etc/apt/preferences` file and the files in the `/etc/apt/preferences.d` directory. Usually the file and directory is empty unless you've manually set values. Removing a file will then remove the pin.

Comment: what if that file and folder are empty? How do I unhold it then? and should I? refering to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449399/why-is-duplicity-set-on-hold-in-apt-get